# MySQL - parse and move data from table 1 to table 2

Tags: mysql, substring

Here's my situation - I have a large text table downloaded from the web and it is a series of 5 variables with fixed widths on each line - "space" delimited.

I'm using phpMYADMIN to upload data (I've been successful with comma-delimited uploads in the past), but this particular table is so "beautiful" and "easy to use" I'd like to upload it and learn about uploading fixed width tables into a db.

On the web I found a suggestion to upload the fixed width table as a series of single rows, then do something with it later.
That was successful.

So now I have a table named "monolith" with one column and 90,000 rows with each row about 450 characters long.

Also, from the same page, they suggested using simple MySQL code on the "monolith" table, parsing each row, and putting those variables in the target table. I played around with that code and finally decided on this:

```
INSERT INTO icd10new
    (icd10order, icd10code, icd10header, icd10short, icd10long)
SELECT SUBSTRING(1,5) AS 'icd10order',
    SUBSTRING(7,7) AS 'icd10code',
    SUBSTRING(15,1) AS 'icd10header',
    SUBSTRING(17, 60) AS 'icd10short',
    SUBSTRING(78, 255) AS 'icd10long'
FROM monolith;
```

The code "completes", but the table is either completely empty (correct number of total rows) or the third variable is filled with "15".

I've tried the code with and without single quotes, put all the substrings in a VALUE(), and nothing seems to work.

Would someone be kind enough to point out my errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the string argument for the `substring()` function:

```
INSERT INTO icd10new(icd10order, icd10code, icd10header, icd10short, icd10long)
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, 1,5) AS 'icd10order',
    SUBSTRING(col, 7,7) AS 'icd10code',
    SUBSTRING(col, 15,1) AS 'icd10header',
    SUBSTRING(col, 17, 60) AS 'icd10short',
    SUBSTRING(col, 78, 255) AS 'icd10long'
FROM monolith;
```

(for `col` use whatever the column name is in `monolith`.)

MySQL is converting the digits to strings.  So, `SUBSTRING(1, 5)` is saying:  take the substring starting at character 5 of `'1'`.  That is an empty string.

Comment: hooray! Hooray! HOORAY! It worked beautifully! Thanks VERY, very much! I was looking at it and wondering how it knew which variable to parse, so now it's clear. Again, thanks very much!

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again. I've used the concepts I learned on this thread for many more instances. Excellent comments, and again, thanks! If I could give you a second green checkmark, I would!